# Calculate total water drunk in a day

Tags: java, beginner

I would like to know how I might improve my code?
I just started coding and liking it a few days ago so I am quite new to this whole world...

The objective is to calculate the amount of water one has drunk in a day. Depending on the user's input, the app tells him or her if the amount of water drunk is great or not.

Now I would like know how I might improve this whole code?
And I'd be grateful for some advice (what I could improve etc)...

```
package com.ahmed.everything;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class DrinkingWater {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Amount of water your bottle can hold: ");
    // entering amount of water bottle can hold
    double litre = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("How many bottles have you drunk today? : ");
    // amount of bottles for today
    double bottles = sc.nextDouble(); 
    // calculating water drunk
    double total = (bottles * litre);

    // result
    if (bottles == 1) {
    System.out.print("You've only drunk one bottle today! :(" + "\n");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Today, you have drunk " + bottles + " bottles. Which equals to " + total + " liters of water.");
    }

    // advice
    if (total < 4) {
        System.out.println("You did not drink enough water, drink at least 4 liters to stay healthy!");
    }

    else if (total >= 4) {
        System.out.println("Good job! You've drunk enough water today! :)");
    }
    else;


    //short time span
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    System.out.print(".");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    System.out.print(".");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    System.out.println(".");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

    System.out.println("Did you like our little app? Please review it from 1-5. 1 being considerer as very good and 5 as very bad.");
    int note = sc.nextInt();
    if (note <= 4 || note >= 1) {
        System.out.println("Thanks for your review.");
    }else {
        System.out.println("That's better, we'll do our best the next time");
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Answer (score 3):

**Check your if expression in review part:**

> ```
> if (note <= 4 || note >= 1) {
>     System.out.println("Thanks for your review.");
> }else {
>     System.out.println("That's better, we'll do our best the next time");
> }
> ```

This will always print "Thanks for your review" since whatever the value of note will be always true either for `<= 4` or `>= 1`.

Using an IDE (for example IntelliJ, netbeans, eclipse) helps you mitigate this kind of problems, but it's still better to always review your code.

[image: mitigate always true in if expression]

---

**Confusing result and advise:**

*I'm not sure if the application is happy that I drank enough water or sad because I only drank 1 bottle*.

As stated in your question:

> The objective is to calculate the amount of water one has drunk in a
>   day. Depending on the user's input, the app tells him or her if the
>   amount of water drunk is great or not.

Then I think you don't need to tell them how many bottles they drink or at least remove the sad face to avoid confusion.

[image: confusing result and advise]

---

**User input problems:**

Case 1: What if the user input a letter instead of number? This will happen:

[image]

Case 2: What if the user input a negative number? Then this will happen:

[image]

As you can see in case 1, this will break your program. Although in case 2 the program will not crash, I think it's impossible to drink negative amount of water.

*To solve this kind of issue, you can use try/catch expression*. Something like this:

```
double litre = 0;
boolean isInvalidInput = false;
do {
    try {
        System.out.print("Amount of water your bottle can hold: ");
        // entering amount of water bottle can hold
        litre = sc.nextDouble();
        isInvalidInput = false;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        isInvalidInput = true;
    }
    sc.nextLine();
} while(isInvalidInput || litre < 0);
```

If you use the code above, this will be the output:

[image: tryCatch]

As you can see, the program will ask the same question repeatedly until the user enters a correct input

Comment: Thank you very much for being so kind and reviewing my code. I do not know how to use try/catch expressions yet. Just put it on my to-do list. Thanks again! I'll try it out

Answer (score 1):

- Do not forget to close the `scanner`
- No need for obvious comments, try to comment why not what, we understand what already
- Why do you have the empty `else;` ?
- Be consistent using `println`, no need for + "\n"
- Make use of `printf`
- Use loops or methods instead of copy / paste
- Your last condition is always `true`, add tests to your apps
- `if (bottles == 1)` but no sad face for 0 bottles? It is even worse..
- Initialise / introduce variables just before you need them, not somewhere irrelevant (see how I moved `double total = (bottles * litre);`)

Here is what I have after applying the changes..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class DrinkingWater {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Amount of water your bottle can hold: ");
            double litre = sc.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("How many bottles have you drunk today? : ");
            double bottles = sc.nextDouble();

            if (bottles == 1) {
                System.out.println("You've only drunk one bottle today! :(");
            } else {
                System.out.printf("Today, you have drunk %s bottles. Which equals to %s liters of water.\n", bottles, total);
            }

            double total = (bottles * litre);
            if (total < 4) {
                System.out.println("You did not drink enough water, drink at least 4 liters to stay healthy!");
            } else if (total >= 4) {
                System.out.println("Good job! You've drunk enough water today! :)");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                System.out.print(".");
            }

            System.out.println("Did you like our little app? Please review it from 1-5. 1 being considerer as very good and 5 as very bad.");
            int note = sc.nextInt();
            if (note <= 4 || note >= 1) {
                System.out.println("Thanks for your review.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("That's better, we'll do our best the next time");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Keep up the good work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time as well. I'll try to see if I understand everything it now does and will get back to you asap :)